# QuestDB ILP - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, questdb

I'm entering data on questDB via ILP, from time to time the application stops entering data, giving me this error:

`System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.CreateException(SocketError error, Boolean forAsyncThrow) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.SendAsyncForNetworkStream(Socket socket, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at QuestDB.LineTcpSender.SendAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine) at QuestDB.LineTcpSender.SendAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at nL1nO95G5COwGUKOWaD1.SC9pfx5voyF(Object, CancellationToken, nL1nO95G5COwGUKOWaD1) at BMPolytec.AppServerKMR.Services.QuestDbService.Blgaq8dfyv() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)`

At the moment I have 3 connections open to questDb and each of them writes data into a table, we're talking about 60 rows per minute.

I have 4 identical PCs running with the same software and only on 3 do I have this error. The only difference the 4th application has is that I'm inserting 60 rows every 100ms instead of every minute.

QuestDB version: 7.1.3

'SpeedSender = await LineTcpSender.ConnectAsync(Configuration.IpAddress, Configuration.Port, tlsMode: TlsMode.Disable);
while (true)
{
try
{
if (SpeedQueue.Count > 0)
{
while (SpeedQueue.Count != 0)
{
SpeedClass speed;

```
                        lock (_speedLock)
                            speed = SpeedQueue.Dequeue();

                        SpeedSender.Table("Speed")
                            .Column("Speed", speed.Speed)
                            .Column("Type", (int)speed.SpeedType)
                            .At(DateTime.UtcNow);

                        await SpeedSender.SendAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _log.Error(e, $"Dequeue speed");
            }

            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }'
```

Comment: Have you checked server logs for any errors? By default ILP server will close the connection when it receives an invalid ILP message (this can be changed with the `line.tcp.disconnect.on.error` config option).

Comment: Yes, I checked but found only this error 

2023-05-23T13:48:18.804542Z E i.q.c.w.WalPurgeJob could not delete directory [path=d:\KMR\QuestDB\db\Production~8\wal6, errno=5]

Comment: Are you running the server on Windows? If so, error code 5 means "Access is denied." (see https://questdb.io/docs/troubleshooting/os-error-codes/#windows-error-codes). In any case, this shouldn't lead to closed ILP connections. Could it be the case that you have a firewall on your machine closing the connection?

Comment: This machine is running on local network so firewall is down, and there isn't antivirus

Comment: Then it's really puzzling. If you can come up with a reproducer and share it in a GH issue, that would be great.